# reacjs animate placeholder like typewriter text - redux form with material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, material-ui, redux-form

I am trying to work on an application with placeholder updating. They want an animation that is like a type effect. I've tried to port the ideas from an older post [reactjs - redux form and material ui framework -- with auto type - and clearing field functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64254162/reactjs-redux-form-and-material-ui-framework-with-auto-type-and-clearing/64322974?noredirect=1#comment113779931_64322974) .

https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-glitter-vg0et?file=/src/Home.js
My current sand box for this. I got it working on my actual application - but I don't understand why its not showing here.

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. You already have a working sandbox from your other question - https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bell-z8nhf..

Comment: yeah but its not a clean approach --

Comment: Why not? What exactly is not clean enough? If you want to use `typeAnimation`, I'm not sure I can see a better approach..

Comment: its just things all split up -- some in the constructor, some in componentDidMount -- listening on a document.activeElement isn't really react orientated? the searchInput ref and the setting of the attribute - doesn't seem a pure way to go

Comment: the sandbox doesn't appear to work - not sure why

Comment: It is working for me. I understand that the part that you want is inside the project and you're looking for help to extract it but it's not actually a question so it's not quite suite to StackOverflow. Having said that, the key is to have an input which its value coming from the state and calling to [`typeAnimation`](https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-bell-z8nhf?file=/src/Utility/Utility.js:648-931) and updating the state as callback. This is the direction, I'm sure you can get it from here :)

Comment: no that's the wrong sandbox -- this is where the version I've implemented has failed - https://codesandbox.io/s/lucid-glitter-vg0et?file=/src/Home.js -- but it seems to work on my localhost